# Change date to string

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, ssms

I have this code

```
select Key
      ,CAST(LEFT(CAST(Key as nvarchar(8)),4)+'0101' as int) as YearaFirstKey
FROM DimDt WHERE Key > 0
```

I need to change this code to string = cStr() , int as cInt(), use substring mid(). But I don't know how. If I print out the code, it shows this:

[image]

Comment: Cast it. What is the question really?

Comment: you have shown us what you get, which is the first day of the year, as an ISO date formatted string.  But what format do you want?  Show us for the first one '20011231'

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask]. Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT [key], CONVERT(varchar(30), CAST([key] as datetime), 103) as strDate
```

with your format code chosen from

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

+++++

your date is in iso format as a string, so it is simple to change it to a date type, then format the date type using built in SQL functions

Comment: ISO yyyymmdd - is 112 code. And for example 20190117 missing.

Comment: his existing data seems to be ISO 112 formatted string, which I've always found to convert directly to a date.